# Using language models for term weighting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, n-gram, text-classification

I understand that scikit supports n-grams using a Vectorizer. But those are only strings. I would like to use a statistical language model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model) like this one: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/model/ngram.html.

So, what I want is a Vectorizer using the probability as term weight instead of let's say tf-idf or simply a token count. Is there a reason why this is not supported by scikit? I'm relatively inexperienced with language modeling, so I'm not sure if this approach is a good idea for text classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what do you mean by **term**. If - as usual - term is just a word, then a probability model will work the same as... simple tf weighting (even without idf!). Why? Beacause empirical estimator of `P(word)` is just `# word / # all_words`, and as `# all_words` is constant, then the weight becomes just `#word`, which is simple **term frequency**. So in this sense, scikit does what you need.

Ok, so maybe you want to consider context? Then what kind of context? Do you want to analyze independently `P(pre-word1, word)` and use it as a weighted sum for `word`? Then why not `P(word, post-word1)`? Why not `P(pre-word2, pre-word1, word, post-word1, post-word2)` etc.? Why not to include some reweighting based on unigrams when bigrams are not available? The answer is quite simple, once you go into using language models as a weighting schemes, amount of possible introductions grows exponentialy, and there is no "typical" approach, which is worth implementing as a "standard" for a library which is **not a NLP library**.